# SMB share on AD domain keeps asking for credentials

Tags: samba, windows-server

I run a network with Active Directory on Windows server 2016. I use OMV3 (based on debian) for my samba shares.

It works well with some users on Windows (SMB share mounts without asking password) but doesn't work with my Admin user on Windows server.

SMB server log file says that when i try to connect with admin user :

```
2017-12-25T17:56:01+0100 omv smbd[1597]: gss_accept_sec_context failed with [ Miscellaneous failure (see text): Failed to find cifs/OMV@HOME.LAN(kvno 2) in keytab MEMORY:cifs_srv_keytab (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)]
2017-12-25T17:56:01+0100 omv smbd[1597]: [2017/12/25 17:56:01.067539,  1] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:541(gensec_spnego_parse_negTokenInit)
2017-12-25T17:56:01+0100 omv smbd[1597]: SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

I guess it has something to do with the keytab file on my OMV server. I'm using the one generated by REALM / SSS but maybe i should generate one myself for this to work ? Explanations on how to do that would be very welcome !!

Thanx !!

Comment: Have you tried mapping the drive with another credential like a domain AD credential. Otherwise is this "my admin" account an AD account in Domain Admins or the domain admin or what? Could it be that you have not added this admin account to the security group or explicitly to have access to the share and the folder? Since you say it works for "some users" without password, I can only assume these are domain accounts that have access to the share security ACL security, etc. wise whereas perhap the admin account simply needs the same just in case check to confirm it's not something that simple.

Comment: Turns out you were wright. I had to map UID and GID for admin to have it listed under OMV users interface, then modify privileges and acl for shared folders to allow admin then it works perfect, thanx !

Comment: Sure you can add this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE**

**Items to consider . . .**

> 1. Try mapping the drive with ***another credential*** like a domain AD user account credential.
>
>    - **GUI**   [image]
>    - **Command Line**
>
>      `NET USE Y: "\\servername\sharename" /USER:<username> <password>`
> 2. Grant the admin account [share and folder security permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx)
>      via a security group or perhaps explicitly so be sure it has access to
>      the resource and authentication will be allowed to it with the admin
>      account.
>
>    - [How Permissions Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx)

If it works for some accounts without a password, then maybe those are domain accounts that have access to the share and folder ACL security, etc. Perhaps the admin account getting the error otherwise simply granted permission to the shared folder resource.